# class - variable declaration-attributes

Tags: java

New to Java, so please bear with me!

Can I know why this is wrong please?
No errors in declaring the map hashmap, but errors when I try to fill them with some pairs.
It does not give errors if I fill them in a constructor.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test 
{
    static String pos_Let ; //letter coordinate for map
    static int pos_Num;     // number coordinate for map
    static int pos_LetNum ; //number reference of letter from HashMap let

    Map o = new HashMap (); 
    o.put(6, "O");
    o.put(7, "O");
    o.put(9, "O");
    o.put(10, "O");
    o.put(12, "O");

    Hashtable p = new Hashtable();
    p.put (10,"P");
    p.put (11,"P");  
}
```

Comment: "but errors" doesn't tell us anything about the error you're getting. I *strongly* suspect that when you provide the error description, you'll find that searching in Stack Overflow for that exact error message will find lots of duplicates.

Comment: The answer from tibtof is solving your **current** problem. But your real problem is that you are too fast for your current skill level. You have no understanding of the basic structure of java classes; but yet you are "already" adding things like hashmaps. So you run into problems; to them here. In other words: you expect that the people here **train** you. But that is not the intention of this site. My personal recommendation: start with super small examples. Type them, run the compiler, execute them. Or at least: do as Jon says. Avoid asking what was asked here thousands of times before.

Answer (score 3):

You're writing code outside a method or a static/initialization block. In Java it's not allowed to do that.

For a quick test you can use the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map o = new HashMap (); 
    o.put(6, "O");
    o.put(7, "O");
    o.put(9, "O");
    o.put(10, "O");
    o.put(12, "O");


    Hashtable p = new Hashtable();
    p.put (10,"P");
    p.put (11,"P");
}
```

If you want to define a map as field and have it initialized you can use either the constructor or an initialization block:

```
final Map<Integer, String> o;

{
    o = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    o.put(6, "O");
    o.put(7, "O");
    o.put(9, "O");
    o.put(10, "O");
    o.put(12, "O");
}
```